# Is it possible to install Windows 8 on a non-ACPI computer?

Tags: windows-8, bios, acpi

I have a computer with a BIOS that doesn´t support ACPI. I tried to install Windows 8 but the setup said I cannot install Windows 8 without ACPI. After some research I found out that this is since Vista.

Is there any option to install Windows 8 even if the BIOS doesn´t support ACPI?

Comment: Paedow can you do me a favor and correct some? It'd only be one change and they don't allow that but the grammar nazi in me can't stand it.

Comment: @Griffin: you can edit questions for spelling etc. See the "edit button" at the end of the question.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I can yet you need to edit a certain number of characters before it will allow you to click the done thing. At least that's what it has done in the past.

Comment: A MacBook Pro doesn't even have a BIOS, but Windows 8 still runs on it. I'm running it.

Comment: @pratnala: So what's your point? All PowerPC Macs used Open Firmware and all Intel Macs use EFI. (U)EFI is fully compliant with ACPI tables/firmware. The latter is used at runtime, whereas the former is mainly used during the bootstrap process. So Macs not having a BIOS is irrelevant since they have its successor which is EFI, which Win8 of course also fully supports (not to mention Apple's EFI implementation is [non-standard and buggy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting), which is why the Linux kernel has [patches](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/6/8/322) to work around them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Windows used to [support](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306003911/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540487(v=vs.85).aspx) APM (and you could in fact even [force](https://web.archive.org/web/20100820012328/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299340) a specific [HAL](https://web.archive.org/web/20090313035837/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781362.aspx) version at install time), but with Vista they dropped it. Build [5048](https://betawiki.net/wiki/Windows_Vista_build_5048#Windows_Boot_Manager) if you want to be specific.

<s>Anyhow, if your system is so old not to support ACPI, I'm really doubtful it could even meet the other minimum requirements for W8 (namely SSE2 and NX bit).</s> [Nevermind](https://superuser.com/questions/662156/bypass-pae-nx-and-sse2-upgrade-requirements-from-windows-8-to-windows-8-1/1750394#1750394).