# Bypass PAE, NX, and SSE2 upgrade requirements from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, pae

On one of my old computers I am having the problem of upgrading to windows 8.1 because my computer does not support PAE, NX, and SSE2. How was I able to install Windows 8 in the first place? I heard the original requirements for windows 8.0 were PAE, NX, and SSE2.

Anyone know a bypass for this on a machine already running windows 8?

IMO 8.1 should have been released in the form of a service pack not an entirely new Windows.

Comment: *IMO 8.1 should have been released in the form of a service pack not an entirely new windows.* [There was nothing stopping them from calling it Windows 8 Service Pack 1 and including these extra requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet).

Comment: If I had a machine that old, I would consider an older edition of Windows or some other operating system, that doesn't reserve as many resources by itself.

Comment: @ta.speot.is True but I believe if there were not new requirements it would have been released via. windows update

Comment: i found a way!here is how to bypass it:
http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/37517-Q-Win-8-bypass-PAE-NX-SSE2-check?p=771750&viewfull=1#post771750

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to upgrade from Windows 8 64-bit to Windows 8.1 32-bit:**

I found the answer but it took me some time.

1. Acquire this file: [en_windows_8_1_x86_dvd_2707392.iso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=524&Languages=en&Architectures=x86&PageSize=10&PageIndex=1&FileId=0)

   If you're not an MSDN subscriber, you can torrent it, but keep in mind sharing copyrighted content is illegal.
2. Download [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html) and mount the ISO file to a virtual drive.
3. Copy the entire contents of the drive to a new folder. Add the [ei.cfg file](http://www.techanger.com/create-windows-8-bootable-usb/) to install windows without a product key.

   ```
   [EditionID]
   [Channel]
   Retail
   [VL]
   0
   ```
4. Use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to make your new folder into an ISO file.
5. Create a [Windows 8 bootable USB key](http://www.techanger.com/create-windows-8-bootable-usb/) and [boot from the device](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/bootusbflash.htm).
6. Install Windows 8.1 without a product key. Select the version of Windows you bought (Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro).
7. After installation you can activate Windows 8.1 32-bit with your legit OEM product key.

**Note:** This is what I had to do to install the 32-bit version since my processor does not support `PrefetchW` and `LAHF/SAHF`.  When I bought Windows 8, it did not come with a 32-bit CD, hence step 1. My product key did not work until after Windows 8.1 was installed, hence step 2-4.

Comment: Just one more thing to note: You can skip creating an ISO image. Create an active primary partition on the USB device (has to be FAT32 in case you'd like to use UEFI), copy all the files, modify them as needed, install the bootmanager (`bootsect /nt60 drive:`) and use it straight away. No need for the extra steps.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reliably circumvent them unless you manage to *at least* obtain the source code for all of Windows and recompile it. (And even then I have some doubts.)

If a program requires SSE2 or something like that, it is generally because it was compiled to use SSE2 instructions – in which case bypassing the requirement checks would mean the program would crash as soon as it reached a place where those instructions were used, because your CPU didn't recognize them. (Having that happen for the OS itself wouldn't be nice, would it?).

Sometimes Windows has code for CPUs both with some feature and without, and detects the supported features at boot time – but I doubt it would bother doing that for something that was listed as required in the first place.

Comment: and/or run an age appropriate OS.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8.1 requires [3 new CPU features that Windows 8 doesn't require](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329092041/http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-CEO-Changes-Pinning-Sites-Form-Factor-Via-CMD#time=06m33s):

> To install a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit PC, your processor needs to support
> CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW, and LAHF/SAHF

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/system-requirements

Comment: Right, but I was wondering how to circumvent it. There seems to be one for 8.1 preview: http://catchtito.blogspot.com/2013/07/bypass-cpu-feature-checks-pae-nx-sse2.html

Comment: @Jonathan You really want to deal with a hack?  You will have to wait until an update patch is released

Comment: It's not going to happen. You'd have to patch every single binary file that comes with the OS and then through Windows Update forever more.

Comment: @Jonathan when a function is executed which is not present, the box crashes. Stay at Win8 or upgrade the hardware.

Comment: Those requirements are for windows 8 64-bit, not 32-bit, and they are `CMPXCHG16b, PrefetchW, and LAHF/SAHF`, not `PAE, NX, and SSE2` like the question. PAE, NX, and SSE2 are required from windows 8

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I know, but he is already running Windows 8, so his CPU supports PAE, NX and SSE2. And the 32Bit one doesn't complain about so he tries to install the 64Bit 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

What is your CPU and how old is it? Windows 8 also requires PAE, NX, and SSE2, not only 8.1, look at @magicandre1981's link above. If your PC is running Windows 8 then it already supports these features

> If you want to run Windows 8 on your PC, here's what it takes:
>
> - Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and SSE2 (more info)
>
> [System requirements](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226092401/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements)

`CMPXCHG16b`, `PrefetchW`, and `LAHF/SAHF` are only required for 64-bit Windows 8. You can still install 32-bit Windows 8.1

For unsupported instructions one can write a patch to trap illegal exceptions and then process in software but it would reduce performance dramatically

Comment: Correct. Though windows might already use these opcodes during boot. In which case timing gets *interesting*. :)

Comment: My specs for the computer are: http://asia.cnet.com/product/dell-dimension-5150-pentium-4-processor-650-3-4ghz-265mb-ram_specs-39096665.htm - I've installed 64bit windows 8, i'm wondering if I could install windows 8.1 32-bit

Comment: according to [this](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/286/Intel_Pentium_4_650_vs_Intel_Pentium_Dual-Core_E2160.html) your Pentium 4 650 CPU supports CMPXCHG16b but not LAHF/SAHF. I'm afraid that you must stay with windows 8 64-bit or install 32-bit windows 8.1. Another option may be dual booting

Answer (score 1):

I have done many attempts to install Windows 8 RTM in a Pentium 4. None succeeded. The only versions that can be installed are Windows 8 Developer Preview and Windows 8 Consumer Preview. But then forget all upgrades and anything Microsoft (such as IE 11). You can do it for experiment, but not for everyday use. Forget Windows 8 RTM and of course 8.1

I hope that will save you time trying in vain...

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the information scattered in the links in the comments.

All Windows 8 versions [officially](https://web.archive.org/web/20160419134234/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482072.aspx) require PAE, SSE2 and NX. Starting from 8.1 though, you also need CMPXCHG16b and LAHF/SAHF (and PrefetchW, but that's kind of a [red herring](https://superuser.com/questions/931742/windows-10-64-bit-requirements-does-my-cpu-support-cmpxchg16b-prefetchw-and-la#comment1645066_941175)) for the 64-bit version. In this sense, switching to 32-bit W8.1 is one way to keep up with updates (ironic that [some](https://superuser.com/questions/187254/how-prevalent-are-old-x64-processors-lacking-the-cmpxchg16b-instruction) 64-bit cpus would have to give up to it in order to work).

But there are actually hacks to remove this requirement. See [W8CPUFeaturePatch](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-8-cpu-feature-patch-bypass-windows-8-cpu-feature-checks.46840/) or [PatchPAE](https://github.com/evgen-b/PatchPAE3).