# What CPU features does Windows 7 require?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

I'm looking for the minimum CPU requirements for Windows 7. Specifically, I want to know if it requires SSE, SSE2, etc.

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) that SSE2 was a requirement for Windows 8, but it doesn't say anything about Windoes 7.

I found this [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements):

> The minimum requirements for Windows 7 are modest by today's standards:
>
> - 1 GHz or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
> - 1 GB RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
> - 16 GB available disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit) -- just for the OS, not applications or data files
> - DirectX 9 graphics processor with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) 1.0 or higher
> - Internet access

Unfortunately, that doesn't say anything about specific CPU features required. Does anyone have the information?

Comment: There were not special requirements.  If it could run Windows XP it ran Windows 7.  SSE2 is only required for Windows 8.1 and greater.

Comment: @Ramhound: so not even SSE is needed? No other CPU features (TSC, CMPXCHG8, CMOV) are required?

Comment: If your machine runs Windows XP it will run Windows 7.  If you want specific CPU requirements look at Windows Vista's requirements.  Windows 7 was targeted to allow upgrades from Windows XP machines though.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 SSE2 [came to be](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/06/21/windows-7-support-dropped-for-cpus-without-sse2/) a requirement for newer Windows 7 updates too, but I'll take we are interested to the situation before that.

If you want to be very specifically CPU-focused, the 32-bit version only needs the [CMPXCHG8B](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/cpu/cx8.htm) instruction that was already a must for XP plus [supposedly](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/bugchecks/5d.htm) RDTSC and an FPU.

But as [noted](https://old.reddit.com/r/retrobattlestations/comments/2t7ekg/how_many_megahertz_do_you_need_to_run_windows_xp/cnwjz94/) by the current record holder of the oldest hardware that can run the OS, what's more likely to give you a bad time once you go far enough behind with the years is ACPI support. APM is [no more](https://superuser.com/a/1576252/567466) since Vista, and until ~1998 (if not even [later](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21767121/the-nextgeneration-system-power-management) with [all](https://web.archive.org/web/20081015011907/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms798251.aspx) the [bugs](https://web.archive.org/web/20070217145721/http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/WindowsMe_S4OS.mspx)) it was the only thing motherboards reliably had.

Fun fact: W7 actually took the bother to [fix](http://web.archive.org/web/20110814164028/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980358) a bug with the original Pentium (which SP1 has built-in).